# Change package name via command line (without Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, command-line, android-manifest

I have an application that needs to be built under multiple package names with minor changes in resources. 
These changes are as simple as changing `Strings.xml`, `Colors.xml`, Package name in Gradle and manifest and changing icons and other resource files. All these changes can be done via the Command line easily.
The hard part that I want to automate is the package name (which is done via Refactor->Rename in Android Studio).

So, I want to change the package name via the Command line including other changes as above.
I've read up the other available answers on StackOverflow and other websites but I couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to achieve that is by creating different product flavours, like so:

```
android {
    ...

    flavorDimensions "version"

    productFlavors {
        flavourA {
            applicationId "com.myapp.name"
        }

        flavourB {
            applicationId "com.myapp.anothername"
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you don't want to set a completely new application ID (package) to every flavour but rather just add a suffix you can do so like the following example:

```
flavourA {
    applicationIdSuffix ".mysuffix"
}
```

Say your application package is `com.test.myapp`. With the suffix it will be `com.test.myapp.mysuffix` when you build your app with `flavourA`.

Then, to build your specific flavour with command line you should do:

**APK**

```
./gradlew assembleFlavourADebug // for debug builds
./gradlew assembleFlavourARelease // for release builds
```

**Bundle**

```
./gradlew bundleFlavourADebug
./gradlew bundleFlavourARelease
```

As for your colour, string, etc. resources you can create resource files specifically for each flavour you're dealing with.

```
src
 |
 +--- main
 |     |
 |     +--- res
 |           |
 |           +--- values
 |                  |
 |                  +--- strings.xml
 +--- flavourA
 |       |
 |       +--- res
 |           |
 |           +--- values
 |                  |
 |                  +--- strings.xml
 |
 +--- flavourB
         |
         +--- res
              |
              +--- values
                    |
                    +--- strings.xml
```

Comment: So from what I've understood, for using different files in different flavours I have to create a folder by the name of that flavour and put that file inside the folder.

Eg: different `/res/drawable/logo.png` for every flavour would be organised as: `res/drawable/flavourA/logo.png` and so on?


Can I also organise folders this way?

Comment: Yes, you can but you don't have to. Only if on that flavour the resource will be different from what you have in src/main/... Note that the same doesn't apply to classes as the compiler will take it as a redeclaration, so you can tackle that situation by having a common interface or class in main and the flavour-specific implementations in each flavour. Again, you can do it but you don't really have to, only if you need

Comment: Btw I fixed the file structure example, please have a look

Comment: Okay, that is very helpful! Because I'm doing upto 100 flavours for an app and this is the best way to handle my use case. I read up more about it and implemented it! Just one more thing, how do I build 50 flavours at once through command line?

Comment: To build all flavours at once in debug mode, run `./gradlew assembleDebug`, for release, `./gradlew assembleRelease`. Replace assemble with bundle if you want an app bundle instead of an apk

Comment: What exactly is your use case if you don't mind me asking? I never heard of any app with that many flavours!

Comment: We basically do a whitelabel management system including other features. It's a subscription based service. So we get their logos, color of the app and the subscription part is handled by the backend. Also, the flavours will go up soon, I suppose upto 500 this year.

I'm sure there are better methods. But we are a small team and this approach works fine for us.

Even the features are handled dynamically by the backend. So one codebase with few things changed works for all.

Comment: Yeah, even with that huge number of variants you'll have to maintain, using flavours is still the best approach. I'm glad I've been able to help

Comment: Hey there! I have another query! Can you just put the relevant strings inside the string.xml file of individual flavours? Does the base strings.xml and main strings.xml get merged or is only the file in the flavour is used? Can this be done, that both files get merged and for the same strings the flavour one gets precedence?

Comment: I'd suggest you to open another question about it. I'll be more than happy to answer it there

Comment: Nevermind! I tried doing it and found the answer. You can have two different files and only the same values will get replaced by the flavour file.